# fixed div overlaps scrollbar

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have problem with fixed div placed in other div with scrollbar. It overlaps scrollbar. it happend under safari and ie 11. When i set z- index to lower than divs with scrollbar than fixed div is under it and it losses interaction (you cant click links etc).Also i tried to make fake fixed position setting it to absolute and with javaScript set "left" to "scrollLeft" div with scrollbar but i cant use this solution because it gives strange effects under Safari and IE10.

Here is code:

HTML

```
<div id="cont">
  <div class="spacer s2"></div>
  <div id="target" class="box2 blue">
     <a href="dfsdfsd">dsfsdf</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#cont {
    width:100%;
    height:800px;
    overflow:hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    z-index:0
}
#target {
    width:200px;
    height:800px;
    position:fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:red;
    z-index:0
}
.spacer {
    width:3000px;
    height:1px;
    z-index:-1
}
```

And link to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jy7ZM/3/).

Please help me ive tried to find solution over 3 days

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd say this is expected behaviour. If you take something out of the documents flow by making it fixed but give it the same height as the parent which has a scrollbar, it will overlap. What are you trying to achieve here? There are probably better ways of doing it...

Comment: i just need to have div that covers `width 100% height 100%` with scrollbar - **cont** inside it i need another div that covers `width 100% height 100%` - **target** and it bahavies like fixed - it stays on its position during scrolling and another div named **spacer** that have `width 3000px` just to activate scrolling. i hope this helps to better understane this case

Comment: If someone (like me) stumbles on this old post this looking for a solution, I've solved a similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35309438/1685196)

Answer (score 1):

change `Position` from `fixed` to `absolute`

```
<div id="target" class="box2 blue" style="width: 200px; height: 800px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; background-color: red; z-index:0">
    <a href="dfsdfsd">dsfsdf</a>
</div>
```

Comment: it doesnt work under chrome, ie 11, firefox on windows 8 scrollbar is still under red box :(

Comment: Strangly it is working on every browser on mac, chrome, safari, firefox, opera. But on windows 8 it doesnt working on any. Here is screen from chrome on windows 8 [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/106929924/i1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Its just because of your this line

```
<div id="cont"  style="width:100%;height:800px;overflow:hidden;overflow-x: scroll;z-index:0">
```

Remove overflow from your style and it will work

It should be looks like

```
<div id="cont"  style="width:100%;height:800px;z-index:0">
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jy7ZM/3/)

**[Updated]**

Please check new [Demo](http://jsbin.com/daqunucu/1/)

Comment: That moves the scroll to the viewport (window). He wants the scroll to be on the div.

Comment: Exactly, i need to have scrollbar on div not on viewport. Thats the whole problem.

Comment: unfortunetly it doesnt work under chrome, ie 11, firefox, on windows 8. scrolbar is stil under red box :(

Comment: Applying the `z-index: 0;` to the parent element with overflow is actually what did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right behavior. It happens in chrome too.

#### Why ?

`position:fixed` should be relative only to the viewport. When you set it on an element, that elemenet is taken out of the flow of any parent and overlapped according to the z-index.

This needs to be treated case by case for correct behavior in my opinion.

Also, maybe this fits your use-case:

```
<div style="display:inline-block;position:fixed; max-height:100px;overflow:hidden;">
    <div id="target" class="box2 blue" style="width:200px;height:800px;overflow:hidden;background-color:red;z-index:0;">
        <a href="dfsdfsd">dsfsdf</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

It wraps the `fixed div` in another one that has `display:inline-block` to enlarge to the size of the content and a `max-height` so it will not go over a fixed size.

If you need it to be **contained** by another div than you can simulate this. You can set position fixed when the fixed div should be visible and change to position absolute when the bottom of the `fixed div` hits the top of the scrollbar.

#### Edit:

You can set an elements height using `top` and `bottom` so you could probably do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kNVP7/) and you calculate the `bottom` with javascript. The `bottom` would become the scrollbar height + padding.

---

Another way would be to calculate the height of the `fixed div` to be calculated like this:

```
var sizeUntillBottomScrollbar = containingDivHeight - containingDivScrollTop;
if(sizeUntillBottomScrollbar  <= scrollBarHeight)
    fixedDivHeight = windowHeight - scrollBarHeight - sizeUntillBottomScrollbar;
else
    fixedDivHeight = windowHeight;
```

The scrollbar height can be calculated (there are other answers on that) and the above code is pseudocode so don't expect it to run as-is.

---

There is also another way if you need it to be 100% all the time. But is quite complicated.

You have to make your *custom scrollbar* functionality (or use a plugin, there are quite a lot) and set on the custom scrollbar a higher `z-index` than the `fixed div` **and also** set `position:fixed` on the custom scrollbar too when the `scrollTop` of the `containing div` is equal to its height - the *custom scrollbar* height.

Comment: in my case `target` have to be `height 100%`. I cant trim it with another div to force it to not cover scrollbar because on every browser scrolbals behaves different. on mac they are autohiding and overlaping conent on windows they ar not and they have different heights

Comment: Check the updated answer. Hope it is not too difficult.